# Multithreading: how to make GUI thread for showing image non-blocking and worker thread for processing image synchronization in wxthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am getting started with the wxThread.

I have shown the video in the GUI thread with wxWidgets. And now I want to handle each frame with opencv like drawing one circle in each frame. At the beginning, I have done the processing in the GUI thread. But when I run the program, I find that the image in the GUI isnot shown continuously and some image doesnot include the circle.

I have realized that image processing part is not put into the GUI thread. I should creat a new thread to complete the image processing part.

But I don't know how to how to make GUI thread and worker thread synchronization, it means that it can make the GUI thread non-blocking and the worker thread process the frame with opencv. Although I konw the wxthread tutorial, I couldnot deal with the problem about how to share the data between the two wxThread.

Could anyone have some ideas about it or some reference? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty extensive section on thread synchronization in the wx-wiki
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication

For background-tasks I like to use the "post event to main thread" approach
This might also work for you. - Send an event whenever your work-thread is done with the processing of a single image and display the image in the event-handler method